# condition in 2 table but select just from one table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables in a mysql database.

I need to select columns just from the first table and do the condition in the 2 table for example :

I have in the first table the columns:

```
amount | date | name | address
```

and in the second I have:

```
amount | date | cin | time
```

The condition would be `WHERE amount = amount and date = date`.

But select just the data from the first table. I dont need to display the data of the second table.

Comment: If you just need the 1st column data, why do you need the 2nd column?  Can you provide some sample data and your desired outcome

Comment: I need the data just from first table but I need too do the condition on the 2 table from extract the informtation

Comment: for exemple I need to show the just the data has the same amount and same date so I need to do a condition on the seconde table but just I need the data the same amount of the first table

Comment: So you only want rows from the 1st table that have a corresponding row in the 2nd? so `SELECT tbl1.* FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.amount = tbl2.amount AND tbl1.date = tbl2.date`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the EXISTS operator to find out whether a corresponding row in the second table exists:

```
SELECT * FROM first_table t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM second_table t2
    WHERE
        t1.amount = t2.amount AND t1.date = t2.date
);
```

This ensures you won't have to use DISTINCT to reduce your resultset, if more than one row with your condition exists in the second table.